# Problem detecting collisions involving rotated pieces in game

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, tetris

I'm trying to create Tetris for an university project. But I'm having a quite difficult time on doing the collisions. Actually, they work, until I try to rotate a piece. After I rotate a piece the collision always returns `True`.

This is the code:

```
def constraint(self):
    if self.shape_y + len(self.shape) == configuration.config['rows']:
        return True

    for shape_row, row in enumerate(self.shape):
        column_index = -1
        for x in range(self.shape_x, self.shape_x + len(self.shape[0])):
            column_index += 1
            if self.shape[shape_row][column_index] != 0:
                if shape_row+1 < len(self.shape):
                    if self.shape[shape_row+1][column_index] == 0:
                        if self.board.board[self.shape_y + 1][x] != 0:
                            return True
                else:
                    if self.board.board[self.shape_y + len(self.shape)][x] != 0:
                        print("qui")
                        return True
    return False
```

shape_y is the row where the shape is located. `len(self.shape)` returns how many rows is the shape because it's coded like a matrix:

Example:

```
 [[0, 1, 0],
  [1, 1, 1]],
```

Is the piece with one block on top and three under.
`Shape` is the matrix that represent the piece.
`Shape_x` is the column where the shape is located.

The board is a matrix like this:

```
self.board = np.array([[0 for _ in range(configuration.config["cols"])]
                            for _ in range(configuration.config['rows'])])
```

where 0 is free, others numbers are block that are not free.

Here a screenshot that show the problem:

[image]

The blue and the green pieces get stuck like a collision occurred but are in "mid air" and nothing really occurred.

EDIT1:

This is the code for the rotation

```
def rotate(self):
    self.board.remove_piece(self)
    self.shape = np.rot90(self.shape)
    self.board.add_piece(self)
```

Where `self.board.remove_piece(self)` and `self.board.add_piece(self)` just remove and add the values inside the board so that i can draw it again. So, basically, the rotation code is just `self.shape = np.rot90(self.shape)`

Comment: What is your code for piece rotation?

Comment: @itprorh66 as requested i have added the code of the rotation in the main post

Comment: Anyone has some suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have actually fixed the problem, the error was inside an index to check on the board.

```
    def constraint(self):
    if self.shape_y + len(self.shape) == configuration.config['rows']:
        return True

    for shape_row, row in enumerate(self.shape):
        column_index = -1
        for x in range(self.shape_x, self.shape_x + len(self.shape[0])):
            column_index += 1
            if self.shape[shape_row][column_index] != 0:
                if shape_row+1 < len(self.shape):
                    if self.shape[shape_row+1][column_index] == 0:
                        if self.board.board[self.shape_y + shape_row + 1][x] != 0:
                            return True
                else:
                    if self.board.board[self.shape_y + len(self.shape)][x] != 0:
                        return True
    return False
```